# How to get JSON value in the angularjs GUI

Tags: html, angularjs, json

How to iterate below json using angularjs in UI.

```
{"messages":[{"operationName":"Operation success","messageKey":"Forbearance Registration Data Overview fetched Successfully!","messageType":"info","fullText":"Forbearance Registration Data Overview fetched Successfully!"}],"status":"Fully Successful","forbearanceRegistration":[{"registrationId":0,"internationalClient":0,"registrationLevelIdentifier":"143333","isConfidential":0,"approvalDate":"2017-12-10","idenComplianceForFinDifficulty":0,"idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin":0,"idenComplianceForConcession":0,"isModificationLossRecog":0,"forbearanceMeasure":[{"measureId":30117,"measureCode":"B-Deferral or capitalisation of the interest payable","measureType":"Temporary","measureDescription":"fdafdsfdsfd","registrationId":0}]},{"registrationId":0,"internationalClient":0,"registrationLevelIdentifier":"143333","isConfidential":0,"approvalDate":"2125-01-19","idenComplianceForFinDifficulty":0,"idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin":0,"idenComplianceForConcession":0,"isModificationLossRecog":0,"forbearanceMeasure":[{"measureId":30116,"measureCode":"B-Deferral or capitalisation of the interest payable","measureType":"Temporary","measureDescription":"fdafdsfdsfd","registrationId":0}]}]}
```

How to iterate  above json value in GUI angularjs.

I need to iterate forbearanceRegistration fields and corresponding inside forbearanceMeasure list.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the first lesson in any Angular tutorial. Please post your attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can represent the json in many types, especially if the are ARRAYS you need iterate with ng-directive, the example i put here with your json is with unordered list, but you can do it with table etc.

**CONTROLLER**
In your controller make a variable where put the json something like this

```
$scope.data = {
  "messages": [
    {
      "operationName": "Operation success",
      "messageKey": "Forbearance Registration Data Overview fetched Successfully!",
      "messageType": "info",
      "fullText": "Forbearance Registration Data Overview fetched Successfully!"
    }
  ],
  "status": "Fully Successful",
  "forbearanceRegistration": [
    {
      "registrationId": 0,
      "internationalClient": 0,
      "registrationLevelIdentifier": "143333",
      "isConfidential": 0,
      "approvalDate": "2017-12-10",
      "idenComplianceForFinDifficulty": 0,
      "idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin": 0,
      "idenComplianceForConcession": 0,
      "isModificationLossRecog": 0,
      "forbearanceMeasure": [
        {
          "measureId": 30117,
          "measureCode": "B-Deferral or capitalisation of the interest payable",
          "measureType": "Temporary",
          "measureDescription": "fdafdsfdsfd",
          "registrationId": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "registrationId": 0,
      "internationalClient": 0,
      "registrationLevelIdentifier": "143333",
      "isConfidential": 0,
      "approvalDate": "2125-01-19",
      "idenComplianceForFinDifficulty": 0,
      "idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin": 0,
      "idenComplianceForConcession": 0,
      "isModificationLossRecog": 0,
      "forbearanceMeasure": [
        {
          "measureId": 30116,
          "measureCode": "B-Deferral or capitalisation of the interest payable",
          "measureType": "Temporary",
          "measureDescription": "fdafdsfdsfd",
          "registrationId": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

**HTML**

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <b>Messages:</b>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="message in data.messages">
        <strong>OperationName:</strong>{{message.operationName}}<br>
        <strong>MessageKey:</strong>{{message.messageKey}}<br>
        <strong>MessageType:</strong>{{message.messageType}}<br>
        <strong>FullText:</strong>{{message.fullText}}<br>

      </li>

    </ul>
    <b>ForbearanceRegistration</b>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in data.forbearanceRegistration">
        <strong>RegistrationId:</strong>{{item.registrationId}}<br>
        <strong>internationalClient:</strong>{{item.internationalClient}}<br>
        <strong>registrationLevelIdentifier:</strong>{{item.registrationLevelIdentifier}}<br>
        <strong>isConfidential:</strong>{{item.isConfidential}}<br>
        <strong>approvalDate:</strong>{{item.approvalDate}}<br>
        <strong>idenComplianceForFinDifficulty:</strong>{{item.idenComplianceForFinDifficulty}}<br>
        <strong>idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin:</strong>{{item.idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin}}<br>
        <strong>idenComplianceForConcession:</strong>{{item.idenComplianceForConcession}}<br>
        <strong>isModificationLossRecog:</strong>{{item.isModificationLossRecog}}<br>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="measure in item.forbearanceMeasure">
            <strong>MeasureID:</strong>{{measure.measureId}}<br>
            <strong>measureCode:</strong>{{measure.measureCode}}<br>
            <strong>measureType:</strong>{{measure.measureType}}<br>
            <strong>measureDescription:</strong>{{measure.measureDescription}}<br>
            <strong>registrationId:</strong>{{measure.registrationId}}<br>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Heres a plnkr to see in action: [example](https://embed.plnkr.co/589d1Eb1wa38BUO6QqIU/)

Comment: Hi Jesus, can you please provide me the data into the table formate.

Comment: just change the code i put and replace ul with table, and li with tr and the content put into td    ex.    `<table><tr ng-repeat="item in data.messages"><td>OperationName:{{message.operationName}}</td></tr>`

Answer (score 0):

Simply :

```
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in objecToIterate"> 
     <div ng-if="value[0]">   // for array fields 
         <div ng-repeat='item in value'>
            <span>{{ item.field1ToDisplay}}<span>
            <span>{{ item.field2ToDisplay}}<span>
            <span>{{ item.field3ToDisplay}}<span>
             ....
        </div>
     </div>
     <div ng-if="!value[0]">   // for non array fields 
       {{value}}
     </div>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I implemented and its working for me.